# MySql encoding issue inserting a row SPRING + HIBERNATE

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, encoding, utf-8

I have a problem on my final year project. I am using Spring + Hibernate to access to my MySql DB. I use Tapestry for view layer.

I need to inser a row where one of the fields matches to an enum field. One of the enum values is "**Polígono**". My DB encoding is set to UTF-8.

I dumped my DB to an XML file (custom format) which I parse. The purppose is creating the DB through this XML file on different devices. I deleted my testing DB and I tried to restore it from the XML file. Word "**Polígono**" appears as it is on the file (UTF-8 encoding) but if I try to insert it using my services and DAOs I get this (tipo_via is the DB column where I am trying to insert that value):

> JDBC exception on Hibernate data access: SQLException for SQL [n/a];
>   SQL state [01000]; error code [1265]; Data truncated for column
>   'tipo_via' at row 1; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Data truncated for
>   column 'tipo_via' at row 1

If I print what I read from the XML (the string I am trying to assign to the row field) I get this on console:
*PolÝgono*
If I create a String with "Polígono" value and I print it I get on console:
*PolÝgono*

Does anybody know how to solve this issue? This is very weird. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I think that the file where I wrote my SQL script for creating the DB was not in UTF8 encoding. I checked the enum values for that field using a DB GUI manager (SQLYog) and I checked that those values were wrong encoded. I fixed it and problem is gone!